# How can I fix Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x52879984) on my appdelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am making an uncomplicated game for IOS app store. The game has been working fine up until this point. Suddenly, I have come across an error: when I play the game for a small amount of time on my iPhone 5s then I press the home button to return to the home menu and then go back into the game, it crashes with this error on the appdelegate:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x52879984).

The game is fine until I try to go back into the game, crashing after the app enters the foreground.

This does not happen on other devices such as my Iphone 7. I have researched into it and I believe it may have to do with my memory allocation as I have not bothered to manage the memory at all in the hope swift and spritekit can sort it out for me because it is a simple game.

I have tried breakpointing the app just before it crashes and checking variables which seem to be there. I have tried completely wiping the game scene in the UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification and creating a new game scene in the willEnterForegroundNotification to no avail.

I have turned on the address sanitizer diagnostic tool in the scheme and the console prints out:

> ==2288==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: negative-size-param: (size=-1377549668)
>       #0 0x7435c8 in wrap_memset (/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5AF965C7-7D31-4B7B-97D2-5DBA7BEDCA9E/xxxxxx.app/Frameworks/libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib:armv7s+0x175c8)
>   Address 0x528e4908 is located in the high shadow area.
>   SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: negative-size-param (/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5AF965C7-7D31-4B7B-97D2-5DBA7BEDCA9E/xxxxxx.app/Frameworks/libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib:armv7s+0x175c8) in wrap_memset
>   (lldb)

And the error changes to

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x4a51c740)

My appdelegate is just basic and I have a basic gameviewcontroller which creates a game scene in the viewdidload function.

The game used to work as intended in this scenario: pausing appropriately.

Help will be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Can you share the code on GitHub so I can look into the issue??

Comment: @ADProgress, all material needed to explain the issue /question should be part of the question posted here and not in some external resource. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Andrew hope you have also tried adding Exception breakpoints. If not, you should give it a try.

Comment: For an uncomplicated game, you sure are using a lot of memory lol.  The system is not as forgiving as you think, you need to properly manage your memory.  Check for retain cycles, those things are usually the culprits to memory leakage.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon It does use a lot of memory, though it does appear simple. I declare a variable inside my game scene to access my view controller like so - var viewController: GameViewController! and then I use that variable inside my scene to utilise the functions. Is this correct? I must admit I am quite a noob at this stuff.
My gameViewController has a variable called gameScene which initialises the class gameScene (which runs the show) and then inside gameScene I create this viewController variable. Is that what I should be doing?